# CSS bug on badges page

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just visited the badges page and it seems like CSS has being broken, the footer background doesn't render a background color/image around it's contents, also the right bar is shifted to the bottom. I have attached a screen shot as a reference...

[image]

[image]

You will also see a scroll bar on the footer here...

[image]

> Browser: Firefox 22.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issues has already been reported on meta SO. A fix is ready and should be rolling out soon: [Who broke the Badges page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187955/who-broke-the-badges-page)